# Do we know or have a reference to what was the plague in Num. 11:33?

Tags: numbers

Chapter 11 in the book of Numbers describes how the people of Israel received the quails to satisfy their flesh desire. Later, they took the quails and started to eat them. In Num. 11:33 (KJV) we read:

> <sup>33</sup> And while the flesh was yet between their teeth, ere it was chewed,
>   the wrath of the LORD was kindled against the people, and the LORD
>   smote the people with a very great plague.

I found a cross reference to Exodus 16, which describes a similar situation, but the plague is not mentioned. I have two questions:

- The actions described in both chapters are the same situation?
- We know that many people died because of this plague, hence the name
  `Kibrot-hataava` given to that place, but do we know what actually was this plague? Fire from heaven maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the opening of the same chapter after they had complained they were smote by the fire

(KJV) Numbers 11:1-2

> 1 And when the people complained, it displeased the LORD:  and the LORD heard it;  and his anger was kindled;  and the ***fire*** of the LORD burnt among them, and consumed them that were in the uttermost parts of the camp.   2 And the people cried unto Moses;  and when Moses prayed unto the LORD, the ***fire*** was quenched.

Though the author did not disclose the nature of the plague,but context leads to believe that it could be the fire